# Override default bootstrap css for one my element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in css and I have a problem (maybe it's stupid) with one element: I have a file browse with this css code:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.file-upload {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.file-upload input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
input[readonly] {
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: text !important;
}
```

and this is the output:

[image: browse input]

As you can see the input field has the wrong width, I would like to have this field in all cell. I have noticed that disabling widht:auto in bootstrap css it works:
[image]

There is a way to fix my problem?This is my html code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary file-upload"> Browse&hellip; 
            <input id="idAcquisition" accept=".dat,.zip" type="file" name="file" data="km"/>
        </span>
    </span> 
    <input id="datName" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

***UPDATE :***

with width:100% ! important it overrides bootstrap but the size is the same, if I increase this value the input field isn't responsive

Comment: Did you try writing this in your CSS file: `.form-inline .input-group .form-control { width: 100% !important; }` ?

Comment: yes it works but what value I use? 100% doesn't change the width and if I increase the input field become no responsive

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few options really.

You can add the important flag after you're CSS that you wish to take priority.

https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Or you can make your CSS more specific like the CSS below. This would then override all the bootstrap settings that are already defined.

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

```
.input-group .input-group-btn .file-upload input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100%; // You need this to override the bootstrap width
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: with width:100% ! important it overrides bootstrap but the size is the same,  if I increase this value the input field isn't responsive

Comment: Can you recreate in a plnkr or jsfiddle?